# How to write an ID, within a class of a class in css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to target the following element in css to change a property but I'm having issues correctly writing it in css.

How would I target

```
<div class="footerSubMenu pull-right" id="footerRight2">
```

as shown to me in google chrome inspect element.

Would it simply be:

```
div.footerRight2.footerSubMenu.pull-right{}
```

Comment: The element ID is always unique and usually you don't need to **mix** element id with element style naming. So you can either *take* your element by the id or apply a style for all elements that have the given style class name. Have a look at the [W3C CSS tutorial](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_basics).

Comment: @pasty: An element with an ID may or may not have those classes so it isn't completely wrong to select by an ID and classes. Although to be fair, if you even have an ID with "Right" in its name and a class with "right" to begin with...

Answer (score 2):

An ID selector begins with a `#`, and a class, `.`. Use the appropriate delimiter for the appropriate identifier:

```
#footerRight2.footerSubMenu.pull-right
```

Using `.` for all three as you are doing doesn't make sense since you're looking for one ID and two classes, and not three classes.

If you just want to target `#footerRight2` regardless of what classes it has, you should use the ID selector by itself. You only need the classes if you want to apply styles to this element only when it has those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Since `id` is unique, you just need to use:

```
#footerRight2 {

    /* Your styles here */    

}
```